# Cassandra proxy to control read/write throughput

Tags: cassandra

I am using different versions of Casandra in my environment where I have 60 nodes are running for different applications. Each application is connecting to its own cluster. I am thinking about abstracting the Cassandra IP from app drivers.
Application will communicate to one proxy IP which will redirect traffic to appropriate Cassandra cluster. The reason behind this thinking is to merge multiple clusters and control the read/write throughput from proxy based on the application.
If anyone knows about pg_bouncer for Postgresql, I am thinking something similar to that.
Have anyone worked in such a project? Can you please share some idea?

Thanks.

Comment: is there a reason not to just use different DCs and partitions or tables vs different clusters? Usually thats just handled in data model instead of separating at cluster level which is massively more difficult.

Comment: We are thinking to control the space usage, read/write throughput usage etc. based on keyspace. Also provide data as a service where developers don't need to  know multiple IPs for multiple cluster.
Can I achieve it with data center? Please let me know.